# Primefaces Dialog framework open dialog from <p:poll>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, ajax-polling, dialog-framework

Salam,

I'm trying to show a notification in a dialog dynamically from a `poll` component but it doesn't seem to work !!

```
<p:poll interval="15" listener="#{notificationBean.showNotification}" />
```

the action works well when i use it with a `commandButton`.

```
<p:commandButton value="View" icon="ui-icon-extlink" actionListener="#{notificationBean.showNotification}" />
```

This is my actionListener's code:

```
    public void showNotification() {
        System.out.println("showNotification");
        Map<String,Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        options.put("resizable", false);
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .openDialog("notifications/notify", options, null);
    }
```

I'm working with PF 6.0

Can't figure out what happens :(

Comment: Try with this:`<p:poll interval="15" listener="#{notificationBean.showNotification}" autoStart="true"/>`
and let me know

Comment: it doesn't work, and it's logical, because the default value of the 'autostart' attribute is "true", The problem is that in my console i get 'showNotification' and the dialog doesn't show !

Comment: Why do you need to go to the backend to show the dialog?

Comment: I'm observing an Event, so when it triggers, il have to notify the user by showing a dialog

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following to your p:poll `oncomplete="PF('DIALOG_WIDGETVAR').show()"/>` or `oncomplete="PF('DIALOG_WIDGETVAR').loadContents()"/>`

Maybe you also have to add `update` within `<p:poll>` so content of dialog is updated.